# Syntax for passing props to ReactMarkdown styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, markdown

I am trying to render some links using `ReactMarkdown` in a `React` component, which needs some props to be passed to use special styling.

`Links` is my styled component which I am applying to `paragraph` property under `renderers` in `ReactMarkdown`. However `Links` to work I need to pass `linkColor={linkcColor}` `props`.

**Code:** Part of my code is where `Container` is another `styled.div`

```
 <Container>
    {websites.map((website, index) => (
      <div key={'website' + index}>
        <ReactMarkdown
          source={`[${website.websiteName}](${website.externalUrl})`}
          unwrapDisallowed={true}
          renderers={{ paragraph: Links, link: Linkrender }}
        />
      </div>
    ))}
  </Container>

  const Links = styled.div`
   color: ${(p) => p.linkColor};

   ::before {
     content: ' ';
     white-space: pre;
   }

   ::after {
      content: '  /';
      white-space: pre;
   }
  `;
```

**Tried:** The following. But it hasn't worked. It loses the `source` for `ReactMarkdown` completely and just `style` is applied to empty `div`.

```
 <ReactMarkdown
          source={`[${website.websiteName}](${website.externalUrl})`}
          unwrapDisallowed={true}
          renderers={{ paragraph: ({linkColor}) => (
                         <Links {...linkColor={linkColor}} />),  <<<<<<<<<<<<< tried this
                       link: Linkrender }}
        />
```

Is the syntax correct? What could be the reason for this not to work? Is it because my styled component is a `div` which is getting applied on a `<p>`? Here `Linkrender` is another styled component custom made which is `<a>`, and that I can't change.

Answer (score 0):

One way that worked was applying a `styled.div` as a wrapper and apply a specific styling to the `paragrah` in `ReactMarkdown`. Look at the arrows inside the code that explains what to do.

```
  <Container>
    <Heading>{`${textStripeHeading}:`}</Heading>
    {websites.map((website, index) => (
      <Links key={'website' + index} linkColor={linkColor}>     <<<<<<<<<<< add <Links> here
        <ReactMarkdown
          source={`[${website.websiteName}](${website.externalUrl})`}
          unwrapDisallowed={true}
          renderers={{ paragraph: MarkdownStyle, link: Linkrender }}   <<<<<<<<< create new style.p with style and apply to paragraph
        />
      </Links>
    ))}
  </Container>

   const MarkdownStyle = styled.p`
      ::before {
        content: ' ';
        white-space: pre;
      }

     ::after {
      content: '  /';
      white-space: pre;
     }
   `;
```

This is just one solution that worked. I am waiting for others to offer better solution.